# Показать/скрыть <div>, не работает с новой библиотеке jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Есть код:

```
<span class="complete">Содержимое</span><span class="more">Показать 
больше...</span>


$(".more").toggle(function(){
    $(this).text("скрыть...").siblings(".complete").show();    
}, function(){
    $(this).text("все даты...").siblings(".complete").hide();    
});
```

Он работает с библиотекой:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
```

Но не работает с новой версией:

```
<script> 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
```

<strike>Как дальше жить?</strike> Как починить?

Comment: почитать, в чем разница между этими двумя версиями?

Comment: К сожалению, я ничего не понимаю JavaScript :(
Код нашел на просторах интернета, а вставить куда надо все-таки сумел.

Comment: а вы уверены, что код работал? `toggle` принимает совсем другие параметры https://jquery-docs.ru/toggle/

Comment: @ThisMan http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: ThisMan, да, работает, вот демо: http://jsfiddle.net/zA23k/215/

Comment: @Regent понял, что этот обработчик удален с версии 1.9, а что на что менять - не понятно.

Comment: Не надо вам менять библиотеку. Смысла - ноль.

Comment: @KAGG Design, не работает другой функционал на 1.8, а две библиотеки как я понял сложно использовать (конфликтуют).

Comment: @Pantera, ура спасибо, все работает!!!

Comment: @Pantera, сорри я тут новенький, не до конца разобрался, вроде бы отметил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".more").click(function(){
  $(this).siblings(".complete").toggle();
  $(this).text($('.complete').is(':visible') ? 'less..' : 'more..');
});
```